# Trying to build a program to organize safety data and display it in graphs

Tags: python, statistics

I'm pretty new to coding, I've done more with HTML and CSS than anything, but now I'm trying to learn a new language because I have an idea for something I want to build. I'm not exactly sure what language would be the best for this. I've been trying to learn a little python, but I want to make sure I'm on the right road. What I'm trying to build is a program that would let me have a form that we would fill out anytime we have an accident at my job, the form would have questions like, type of injury, department associate was working in, time of injury, day of the week, etc.. It would also keep track of our Non-Meds, Medicals and osha reportables by shift and in total for the week, month, year or whatever time span you want to see and show it in graphs or pie charts, so the information could be used to determine where our weaknesses are in terms of safety. So the form would basically take the information you input, and store it in the correct category and automatically update the charts. I know I'm probably trying to take on something kind of big, being as I don't know a whole lot about coding, but I feel like working on this would give me a good starting point. I've already made a spreadsheet in excel to get us by for now, but I would like to make something thats more user friendly to update anytime an accident occurs. So what language do you guys think would being a good one to learn to tackle this?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use C# and WPF for creating the input form, because it is pretty easy to build GUIs for windows with C# and Visual Studio. Then I would store the input information into a SQL database for easy querying of the data. To analyze the data I would use python with MatPlot lib to make graphs and visualize the data in an understandable way. Then the C# GUI could display the graphs generated by python in a classical GUI with dropdowns or tabs or whatever fits the purpose.